# Why is the text size different in similar items inside a bottomNavigationBar in Google Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, material-design

I believe I have discovered some unexpected behavior in the bottomNavigationBar widget from Google Flutter.

**Behavior**: Similar `items` of type `BottomNavigationBarItem` have different sized text, seemingly due to the presence of some extra padding on every item except the first item.

**Steps to reproduce**: Run the below dart code on an iOS emulator and/or Android emulator.

**My question**: Why is the rendered text a different size in the bottomNavigationBar, namely 'Make Call A' vs 'Make Call B'? If it is due to extra padding somewhere, where is that coming from? What can be done to get rid of the extra padding?

**Code**:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData.light(),
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: Text('Test Application'),
        ),
        body: Container(),
        bottomNavigationBar: new BottomNavigationBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          items: [
            new BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: new Icon(
                Icons.phone,
                color: Color(0xFF572F88),
              ),
              title: new Text(
                "Make Call\nA",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
            new BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: new Icon(
                Icons.phone,
                color: Color(0xFF572F88),
              ),
              title: new Text(
                "Make Call\nB",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Illustration of problem**:
[iPhone 11 Pro Max Emulator Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLJPC.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the difference in the text size for the two items is that the `BottomNavigationBar` has different font sizes for the its texts depending on if they are selected or not.

Font size for the selected item defaults to 14.0 [[selectedFontSize](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar/selectedFontSize.html)] while that of the unselected item defaults to 12.0 [unselectedFontSize](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar/unselectedFontSize.html).

So it's not due to extra padding.

You can ensure the text sizes are uniform by setting them to be the same value. Like below:

```
BottomNavigationBar(
    selectedFontSize: 12.0,
    unselectedFontSize: 12.0,
    //rest of the code
)
```